# HTML Vertical Line with Buttons in The Middle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to set a vertical line with buttons in the middle with bootstrap.

Using Bootstrap simple vertical line:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-right:20px; border-right: 1px solid #ccc; " >                              
        Area 1
    </div>  
    <div>
        Area 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Above only shows a vertical line, but I wanted to be able to add these right in the middle of that vertical line.

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>
```

I couldn't really figure out how to position it using CSS. Is there a good way to go about this? 
Any suggestions?

Edit:
I added -

```
<div class="round" style="position: absolute; top: 40%; right: -13px;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" style="font-size: 1.2em; cursor: pointer;"></span>
</div>
<div class="round" style="position: absolute; top: 55%; right: -14px;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" style="font-size: 1.2em; cursor: pointer;"></span>
</div>
```

It works, but the vertical line is in between the buttons.. Any suggestions on updating this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this something like this

```
 <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">                              
    <div style="padding-right:20px; border-right: 1px solid #ccc; " >Area 1</div>
</div>  
<div>
    Area 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the after selector in css: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp

Using it you could do something like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 myStyle" style="" >                              
        Area 1
    </div>  
    <div>
        Area 2
    </div>
</div> 


.myStyle { 
padding-right:20px; border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }
.myStyle::after{
 font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
 content: "whatever the icon you want is";
}
```

You can then use CSS to position the icons however you want. 
If you'd like to use more than one Icon you could use the :before selector on the button on the right, and the after on the button on the left.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried putting it in a modal but it only showed on the very bottom of the modal.. I just implemented using position relative/absolute. Somehow I feel it'll break when I resize the browser.. =\